# GPUImage: How can I reset the original image (without any filter)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm developing an app, where I can apply filters on an image.
Now I want to create an undo button which resets the original image in the imageView.
How can I do this?

**Parts of the filter code:**

```
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookup = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init]

UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0];
[self->_imagView setImage:adjustedImage];
```

**I try this but it doesn't works:**

```
- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender

{
 _imagView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageOrig.png"];
 [filterNames removeAllObjects];
 [self->_imagView setImage:_imagView.image ];
}
```

Comment: is undo getting called?

Comment: What do you mean with called? If the code is connected with the UIButton?

Comment: Can you verify `self` in undo is the same object as self when you applied filters? I ask because your code seems fine

Comment: Can you just save the original image in it's own UIImage object before you apply any filters to it? This way you can just go back to that in your undo method.

Comment: That's a good way to do it! Thanks. But i don't know how to save the UIImage object and call it back (I'm new in developing iOS Apps). Can you help me to do this?